# Grafana + InfluxDB configuration

Tags: docker, datasource, influxdb, grafana

I installed InfluxDB and Grafana on docker (Kitematic application) and downloaded Telegraf metrics https://grafana.net/dashboards/61.

Then I selected my local http://192.168.99.100:3004/dashboard/new?editview=import and tried to import that telegraf-metrics_rev2.json file.

But I cannot click "save and open" button because for options InfluxDB I have message:

> No data sources of type InfluxDB found.

Could you please give a hint where can I take datasource for Telegraf metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your InfluxDB datasource first.

1. Click on top left Grafana Icon
2. Click on Datasources
3. Use this as a guide to add your InfluxDB datasource - http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/influxdb/
4. And, now import your dashboard.